# Generate 0 and 1, pseudorandom, 16 char long string

Tags: php, random, binary, sha1

I need to generate 16 characters long string (from SHA1 hash), which contains only 0 and 1, with probability 50% (statistically in most cases same amount of 1 in string as amount of 0's).

So i wrote benchmark, and i tried converting each $hash character to binary. 
Results are bad, i mean, if im adding leading zeros to binary converted hash, correct probability is far from correct.
When im not adding leading zeros to binary conversion, probability is close to correct:

```
Percentage all 0 or all 1: 0.0012%
Percentage all 0 or all 1 except 1 character : 0.0146%
Percentage all 0 or all 1 except 2 characters: 0.0812%
```

But its still far from true correct probability that code below should produce which is:

```
Percentage all 0 or all 1: 0.003%
Percentage all 0 or all 1 except 1 character : 0.048%
Percentage all 0 or all 1 except 2 characters: 0.376%
```

How do i know its correct probability? I changed binary conversion to simple mt_rand(0,1) sixteen times (and other confirmation tests).

It must be generated from sha1 hash, to be deterministic by that hash.
Anyone have idea, how to fix my code to produce correct probability results? I tried already for 10 hours straight.

```
    function binary($text){
            $list = '';
            $temp = '';
            $i = 0;
            while ($i < 16){
                    if (is_numeric($text[$i])){
                            $list .= decbin( $text[$i] );//sprintf( "%08d", decbin( $text[$i] ));
                    } else {
                            $temp = ord($text[$i]);
                            $list .= decbin( $temp );
    //                      $list .= sprintf( "%08d", decbin( $temp ));// substr("00000000",0,8 - strlen($temp)) . $temp;
                    }
            $i++;
            }
            return $list;
    }

    $y = 0;
    $trafien = 0;
    $trafien1= 0;
    $trafien2= 0;
    $max = 500000;
    while ($y < $max){

    $time = uniqid()  . mt_rand(1,999999999999);
    $seed = 'eqm2890rmn9ou8nr9q2';
    $hash = sha1($time . $seed);

    $last4 = substr($hash, 0, 40);
    $binary =  binary($last4);
    $final = substr($binary, 0,16);

    $ile = substr_count($final, '0');
    $ile2= substr_count($final, '1');
    if ($ile == 16 || $ile2 == 16){
        echo "\n".$last4 ." " . 'binary: '. $binary .' final: '. $final;
        $trafien += 1;
    }

    if ($ile == 15 || $ile2 == 15){
        $trafien1 += 1;
    }

    if ($ile == 14 || $ile2 == 14){
        $trafien2 += 1;
    }

$y++;
}

$procent = ($trafien * 100)  / $max;
$procent1= ($trafien1 * 100) / $max;
$procent2= ($trafien2 * 100) / $max;
echo "\nPercentage all 0 or all 1: ". $procent . "%";
echo "\nPercentage all 0 or all 1 except 1 character : ". $procent1 . "%";
echo "\nPercentage all 0 or all 1 except 2 characters: ". $procent2 . "%";
```

Comment: Using a uniqid() probably isn't good for a random number generator since it is based on microtime.

Comment: @Devon uniqid() is used only for benchmark purposes, in real code hash is generated in diffirent way

Comment: Why are you generating the hash differently in the benchmark?

Comment: because way you get hash doesn't matter here, it should be unique in benchmark and i don't have for example user_id in benchmark so i use mt_rand + uniqid()

Answer (score 0):

I guess I don't see why you need to reinvent the wheel here or use sha1() when you only use 4 characters and convert to binary.  This seems to work fine:

```
$n = null;
for ($i=1; $i<=16; $i++) {
  $n .= mt_rand(0,1);
}
```

Here is a benchmark script I wrote:

```
// $app for number of appearances
$app[0] = 0;
$app[1] = 0;
$sample = 10000;

for ($t=1; $t<=$sample; $t++) {

  $n = null;
  for ($i=1; $i<=16; $i++) {
    $n .= mt_rand(0,1);
  }

  $app[0] += substr_count($n, 0);
  $app[1] += substr_count($n, 1);
}

print_r($app);
echo "Probability of 0: ".($app[0] / ($sample * 16))."\n";
echo "Probability of 1: ".($app[1] / ($sample * 16))."\n";
```

Output with 10000 sample size:

```
Array
(
    [0] => 80079
    [1] => 79921
)
Probability of 0: 0.50049375
Probability of 1: 0.49950625
```

Output with 100000 sample size:

```
Array
(
    [0] => 799390
    [1] => 800610
)
Probability of 0: 0.49961875
Probability of 1: 0.50038125
```

Comment: I wrote in my post about using mt_rand(0,1), you didn't read my post :P, also said twice that i must do this by hash. It must be deterministic by hash. Believe me if i could i would do this easy way :/

Comment: I know you said that but you didn't explain why.  An explanation of why you need it to be deterministic by hash might make more sense.

Comment: Because i must have proof that i didn't made up this numbers (0/1), and they were created by independent deterministic hash. Anyone can verify then if really this numbers were created by this hash.

Comment: What is the ultimate goal of this code?  I don't see how using the last 4 characters of an sha1 hash adds any sort of verification.  How are they to verify the original hash?  You can't reconstruct it from the the last 16 bits, even if you could why would that be different than a random 16 bits from mt_rand?  Is this a homework assignment or something?  I don't see the point otherwise.

Comment: No its not homework. User doesn't need reconstruct hash, he know how this hash is created ( in live code there is no randomness to creating hash). So he can create whole hash and use known algoritm (this mine above which don't work yet properly) to valid this 16 character long 0/1 :)

Comment: @John, okay.  I suggest you update your original question explaining this so you can get some more valuable input.  Right now, as the question appears, you are just trying to get a random 16-bit  binary string which doesn't appear to be what you're really after at all.

Comment: thanks for involvment :), you are only person that tried to help

Answer (score 0):

Ok i solved it, i overwork this due to lack of knowledge. You can use direct raw binary output of sha1 function sha1(data, true). Then you have true deterministic 0/1 randomness :)